# wildcard in httpd conf file?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

Here is an example httpd config I'm currently using:

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /home/folder
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm wondering, is it possible to have a wildcard for the ServerName & ServerAlias variable?

Reason for asking is I have some software that is shared among multiple URL's all controlled in a CMS and it's kind of a pain to add new domains via ssh everytimee. And before someone points out a security hole, the software does check the current URL before doing any webpages :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, replace `ServerAlias www.mysite.com` with `ServerAlias *.mysite.com` and you should be good to go.

Comment: would that work with full domains though? such as "ServerAlias *"?

Comment: If you need that, just make it the first virtual host on the system as Sameer has indicated below. The other option is to dedicate an ip to it and have no NameVirtualHost setup on that ip.

Answer (score 1):

Make this virtual host entry the first entry. By default if there is no match then apache uses the first entry as the default entry.

Check under the "Main host goes away" title.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html